# C++ set iterator causing error. Expression: map/set iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, set

```
int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        ll n;
        cin >> n;
        set<int> list;
        vector<ll> vec;
        for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            list.insert(i);
        }
        bool more = true;
        while (more) {
            vec.clear();
            auto it = list.begin();
            if (list.size() == 1) {
                cout << "1 1" << endl;
                break;
            }
            vec.push_back(*it);
            ll num = *it;
            list.erase(it);
            int count = 1;
            auto itt = list.begin();
            bool y = false;
            for (itt; itt != list.end(); ) {   // ...(1)
                if (checkPrime(*itt)) {
                    vec.push_back(*itt);
                    num = *itt;
                    list.erase(itt);
                    count++;
                }
                else if (gcd(num, *itt) == 1) {
                    vec.push_back(*itt);
                    num = *itt;
                    list.erase(itt);
                    count++;
                }   
                else itt++;
            }
            if (count == 1) {
                cout << "2 1" << num << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << count << " ";
                for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
                    cout << vec[i] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            if (list.size() == 1) more = false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program is trying to find co-prime numbers in a range. But after every last iteration in (1), it is causing an error stating Debug assertion failed! Expression map/set iterators incompatible. Why is this happening? **checkPrime** and **gcd** are functions to check whether a number is prime or not and to find gcd of two numbers respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying a container while iterating it is not a trivial operation. 
When you erase the **current iterator** it is no more a valid iterator. This generates the incompatible operation after you erase it:

```
list<int> l;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) l.push_back(i);
for (auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); )
    l.erase(it);
```

After you erase the current iterator:

1. The **current iterator** becomes invalid
2. The place of **current** is taken by the **next** element in the list (++).

This one does not cause the error:

```
list<int> l;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) l.push_back(i);
for (auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); )
    l.erase(it++)
```

Note that you can't to this with a vector. But with vectors you can do this:

```cpp
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    int current_position = 0;
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it = v.begin() + current_position)
    {
        //some logic there in current position which can change
        v.erase(it);
    }
```

Even more complex things comes with maps and trees.
So this is how you should erase: list.erase(itt++);

Also you code is little bet over engineered:

```
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        ll n;
        cin >> n;
        set<int> list;
        vector<ll> vec;
        for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; i++)  list.insert(i);
        bool more = true;

        if (list.size() == 1)
        {
            cout << "1 1" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        while (list.size() > 1)
        {
            vec.clear();
            auto it = list.begin();
            vec.push_back(*it);
            ll num = *it;
            list.erase(it);
            for (auto itt = list.begin(); itt != list.end(); )
            {
                if (checkPrime(*itt) || gcd(num, *itt) == 1)
                {
                    vec.push_back(*itt);
                    num = *itt;
                    list.erase(itt++);
                }
                else itt++;
            }
            if (vec.size() == 1)
                cout << "2 1" << num << endl;
            else
            {
                cout << vec.size() << " ";
                for (auto n : vec) cout << n << " ";
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```